# Batch script, how to know we are running on system user

Tags: windows, batch-file, system

I am trying to write a windows batch script which detects if it runs under system user to launch an other application. The application needs to run as system. But the batch file launching it will be called by an Admin user.

Here is what I have now:

```
IF "%USERPROFILE:~-13%" == "systemprofile" (
    PUSHD "%~dp0\.."
    CALL "init some variables"
    CALL "my command" %*
    POPD
) ELSE (
    FOR %%X IN (psexec.exe) DO (SET FOUND=%%~$PATH:X)
    IF DEFINED FOUND (
        CALL psexec -s %0 %*
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Must be run as user SYSTEM
        ECHO If psexec is in PATH, it will be automatically used.
    )
)
```

For now I check *%USERPROFILE%* but I guess it is a bad way to do that.

When launching my script with *psexec -s*, *echo %USERNAME%* gives the name of the server with a $ at the end.

What is the best way to know if the batch script is running on system user?
Maybe there is a better alternative to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: `running on system user` do you mean in an elevated command line?

Comment: Why are you going through all this trouble when `psexec -s` already runs as the system account. Seems redundant to me.

Comment: I do not want to force the user to type psexec -s in front of the batch file call. The user will run the batch file as Administrator. I just need to know how to check if the batch file is running as system.

Comment: Why would the user need to run the batch file with `psexec`? Just use `psexec` inside a batch file that calls your other one.

Comment: @Matt I do not know if the user has psexec in PATH. I'll try to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean running with administrator privileges you can check with something like this:

```
OPENFILES >nul 2>nul
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   COLOR CF
   ECHO.You must 'Run as administrator'
   PAUSE
   GOTO :eof
   )
```

Note that the

```
2>nul is needed because 2012 Server and Windows 8 return ERRORLEVEL 0 but output "ERROR: Unable to retrieve data."
```

I don't think it is right that a command returns an error code of 0 but still outputs to STDERR, but...